# How to conditionally render a React component that uses hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The following (albeit contrived) component violates react-hooks/rules-of-hooks (via eslint)

```
function Apple(props){
  const {seeds} = props;
  if(!seeds){
    return null;
  }
  const [bitesTaken, setBitesTaken] = useState(0);
  return <div>{bitesTaken}</div>
}
```

with the following error
`React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?`

I understand that hooks [need to be called in the same order](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation), but this kind of conditional rendering (so long as no hooks are invoked before the return, does not prevent the hooks from being called in the same order.  I think the [eslint rule](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) is too strict, but maybe there's a better way.

**What is the best way to conditionally render a component which uses hooks?**

Comment: What if you put `useState` sentence before `if(!seeds){` line? Documentation states: "This is why Hooks must be called on the top level of our components"

Comment: The `eslint-rule` is there to enforce good practices and proper usage of `React hooks`, therefore you should just move your `hooks` to the top and put your `if` right before you are ready to `render` some `JSX`. That'd be the best and right way to conditionally render a component which uses hooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't conditionally use hooks, so move the hook above the condition.

```
function Apple(props){
  const {seeds} = props;
  const [bitesTaken, setBitesTaken] = useState(0);
  if(!seeds){
    return null;
  }
  return <div>{bitesTaken}</div>
}
```

You can also simplify the rendering like this:

```
function Apple(props) {
  const { seeds } = props
  const [bitesTaken, setBitesTaken] = useState(0)
  return !!seeds && <div>{bitesTaken}</div>
}
```

If `seeds` is falsey, then `false` will be returned (which renders as nothing), otherwise, the `div` will be returned.

I've added the double exclamation point to `seeds` to turn it into a boolean, because if `seeds` is `undefined` then nothing is returned from render and React throws an error.

Comment: I do not like this limitation of hooks, but it seems like the most sensible way to do it within the limitations so I'll accept the answer.  Thank you for the detailed response JMadelaine.

Comment: @Jordan It's not really a limitation. Class-based components work the same way - your `constructor` (which you'd use for initializing your `state`) and `componentDidMount` will get called regardless whether you return `null` or some `JSX` in the `render` method. This is essentially exactly the same thing that's happening here and you're trying to change this behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to split the component.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

const Apple = (props) => {
    const {seeds} = props;
    return !!seeds && <AppleWithSeeds />;
};

const AppleWithSeeds =(props) => {
    const [bitesTaken] = useState(0);
    return <div>{bitesTaken}</div>
};

export default Apple;
```

Advantage of this method is that your components stay small and logical.

And in your case you might have something more than '0' in the useState initializer which you don't want unnecessary at the top before the condition.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for this type of solution

Comment: What's interesting about this approach is that you are basically "conditionally using a hook".